# Recursive renaming VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, recursion, filesystemwatcher

I'm making an application that renames folders and files and it's concept is like this, i have two *Backup Folders* and they have the same contents, let's say `Backup1` and `Backup2`, If i rename a subfolder in `Backup1` that subfolder **IN** `Backup2` should be renamed.  I'm using a `FileSystemWatcher` to monitor for the files that are being renamed

```
Sub FileLogs()
    watchfolder = New System.IO.FileSystemWatcher()

    Dim src As String = Label5.Text

    watchfolder.Path = src
    watchfolder.IncludeSubdirectories = True

    watchfolder.NotifyFilter = IO.NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
    watchfolder.NotifyFilter = watchfolder.NotifyFilter Or IO.NotifyFilters.FileName

    AddHandler watchfolder.Renamed, AddressOf logrename
    'Start monitoring for renames of folders and files
    watchfolder.EnableRaisingEvents = True
End Sub
```

and storing the monitoring renamed items in a `List(Of String)`

```
Dim oldItemName As New List(Of String)
Dim newItemName As New List(Of String)
Private Sub logrename(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.RenamedEventArgs)
    oldItemName.Add(e.OldName)
    newItemName.Add(e.Name)
End Sub
```

This is where the renaming takes place.

```
Dim dest As String = Label6.Text
    For i = 0 To Math.Min(oldItemName.Count - 1, newItemName.Count) - 1
        Try
            My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameDirectory(Path.Combine(dest, oldItemName(i)), newItemName(i))
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    Next
```

This code works only inside the `Backup2\`, but IF i rename a folder inside the `Backup1\Folder\SUB` the folder in `Backup2\Folder\SUB` cannot be renamed. It throws an `ArgumentException` `Argument 'newName' must be a name, and not a relative or absolute path: 'Folder\SUB1'.
Parameter name: newName`

What i think it does is it is renaming the `SUB` in `Backup2` as `Folder\SUB` that's why it has an error, Because of the `watchfolder.IncludeSubdirectories = True` the monitored subfolders are stored as `Folder\SUB` which is good because of the path. But how do i rename it correctly? and how do i do it recursively and multiple Items are renamed?

Comment: Take a look at the methods in Io.Path (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0):

```
For i = 0 To Math.Min(oldItemName.Count - 1, newItemName.Count) - 1
```

Should that be

```
For i = 0 To Math.Min(oldItemName.Count - 1, newItemName.Count - 1)
```